# Magento 2 Recaptcha Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined

Tags: magento2.3.2, recaptcha

I recently updated from Magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.2. I now get the below error on every page. It worked fine on 2.3.1. I have checked to make sure the API website key and secret keys are correct. I have switched to the Luma theme and the error still shows. This is a core module and nobody has ever touched the code. I have done the normal clear cache, compile, upgrade, and removed the static and generated folders but the error still persists.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
at acceptData (jquery.js:3762)
at internalData (jquery.js:3830)
at Function._data (jquery.js:4040)
at UiClass.initCaptcha (reCaptcha.js:161)
at reCaptcha.js:196
at dispatch (jquery.js:5226)
at elemData.handle (jquery.js:4878)
at Object.trigger (jquery.js:5130)
at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.js:633)
at jquery.js:5860
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else who runs into this issue when you upgrade. 2.3.2 adds new fields for the recaptcha and enables all of them. When I disabled the newsletter recaptcha this error was cleared from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved in 2.3.3 but if you want to fix it in 2.3.2 follow the steps below:
create one module with the following structure

[image]

1) module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Levosoft_MSPRecaptchaFixLang" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

2) requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha': "Levosoft_MSPRecaptchaFixLang/js/reCaptcha",
        }
    },
};
```

3) reCaptcha.js

```
'use strict';

define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'MSP_ReCaptcha/js/registry'
    ],
    function (Component, $, ko, registry, undefined) {

        return Component.extend({

            defaults: {
                template: 'MSP_ReCaptcha/reCaptcha',
                reCaptchaId: 'msp-recaptcha'
            },
            _isApiRegistered: undefined,

            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                this._loadApi();
            },

            /**
             * Loads recaptchaapi API and triggers event, when loaded
             * @private
             */
            _loadApi: function () {
                var element, scriptTag;

                if (this._isApiRegistered !== undefined) {
                    if (this._isApiRegistered === true) {
                        $(window).trigger('recaptchaapiready');
                    }

                    return;
                }
                this._isApiRegistered = false;

                // global function
                window.globalOnRecaptchaOnLoadCallback = function () {
                    this._isApiRegistered = true;
                    $(window).trigger('recaptchaapiready');
                }.bind(this);

                element = document.createElement('script');
                scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

                element.async = true;
                element.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'
                    + '?onload=globalOnRecaptchaOnLoadCallback&render=explicit';
                if (this.settings === undefined || this.settings.lang === null || this.settings.lang === undefined) {
                    element.src = element.src + '&hl=' + window.navigator.language.replace(/-.*/, '');
                } else {
                    element.src = element.src + '&hl=' + this.settings.lang;
                }

                scriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(element, scriptTag);

            },

            /**
             * Return true if reCaptcha is visible
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            getIsVisible: function () {
                return this.settings.enabled[this.zone];
            },

            /**
             * Checking that reCaptcha is invisible type
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            getIsInvisibleRecaptcha: function () {
                return this.settings.size !== 'invisible';
            },

            /**
             * Recaptcha callback
             * @param {String} token
             */
            reCaptchaCallback: function (token) {
                if (this.settings.size === 'invisible') {
                    this.tokenField.value = token;
                    this.$parentForm.submit();
                }
            },

            /**
             * Initialize reCaptcha after first rendering
             */
            initCaptcha: function () {
                var me = this,
                    $parentForm,
                    $wrapper,
                    $reCaptcha,
                    widgetId,
                    listeners;

                if (this.captchaInitialized) {
                    return;
                }

                this.captchaInitialized = true;

                /*
                 * Workaround for data-bind issue:
                 * We cannot use data-bind to link a dynamic id to our component
                 * See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657573/recaptcha-the-bind-parameter-must-be-an-element-or-id
                 *
                 * We create a wrapper element with a wrapping id and we inject the real ID with jQuery.
                 * In this way we have no data-bind attribute at all in our reCaptcha div
                 */
                $wrapper = $('#' + this.getReCaptchaId() + '-wrapper');
                $reCaptcha = $wrapper.find('.g-recaptcha');
                $reCaptcha.attr('id', this.getReCaptchaId());

                $parentForm = $wrapper.parents('form');
                me = this;

                // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
                widgetId = grecaptcha.render(this.getReCaptchaId(), {
                    'sitekey': this.settings.siteKey,
                    'theme': this.settings.theme,
                    'size': this.settings.size,
                    'badge': this.badge ? this.badge : this.settings.badge,
                    'callback': function (token) { // jscs:ignore jsDoc
                        me.reCaptchaCallback(token);
                        me.validateReCaptcha(true);
                    },
                    'expired-callback': function () {
                        me.validateReCaptcha(false);
                    }
                });

                if (this.settings.size === 'invisible') {
                    $parentForm.submit(function (event) {
                        if (!me.tokenField.value) {
                            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
                            grecaptcha.execute(widgetId);
                            event.preventDefault(event);
                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    });

                    // Move our (last) handler topmost. We need this to avoid submit bindings with ko.
                    listeners = $._data($parentForm[0], 'events').submit;
                    listeners.unshift(listeners.pop());

                    // Create a virtual token field
                    this.tokenField = $('<input type="text" name="token" style="display: none" />')[0];
                    this.$parentForm = $parentForm;
                    $parentForm.append(this.tokenField);
                } else {
                    this.tokenField = null;
                }

                registry.ids.push(this.getReCaptchaId());
                registry.captchaList.push(widgetId);
                registry.tokenFields.push(this.tokenField);

            },


            validateReCaptcha: function (state) {
                if (this.settings.size !== 'invisible') {
                    return $(document).find('input[type=checkbox].required-captcha').prop("checked", state);
                }
            },

            /**
             * Render reCaptcha
             */
            renderReCaptcha: function () {
                var me = this;

                if (this.getIsVisible()) {
                    if (window.grecaptcha && window.grecaptcha.render) { // Check if recaptcha is already loaded
                        me.initCaptcha();
                    } else { // Wait for recaptcha to be loaded
                        $(window).on('recaptchaapiready', function () {
                            me.initCaptcha();
                        });
                    }
                }
            },

            /**
             * Get reCaptcha ID
             * @returns {String}
             */
            getReCaptchaId: function () {
                return this.reCaptchaId;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

4) registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Levosoft_MSPRecaptchaFixLang',
    __DIR__
);
```

That's it run setup upgrade and clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by a customization and I took the fix from here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9635#issuecomment-313758975

In short: delete the following from `contact_index_index.xml`:

```
<block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
  <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
</block>
```